# How to set the DataGridViewCell to automatically wrap single long word?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, word-wrap

This question is asked here many times but their answers are not working for me.

I am using C# DataGridView to show the data in tabular form. I have some 8/9 columns and around 25 to 30 rows. For each column, I am setting customized width (Some percentage of total screen width and it is different for each column). To achieve it I have set following property

```
    view1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
```

Also, since my application is such that I can't show all the rows at same time but the no. of rows defined by user at a time and for that I am using scrollindex property in timer to scroll view. Also I have customized row height (Some percentage of total screen height). So to do not show all the rows at same time I am using following property

```
    view1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
```

For wrapping I am using

```
    view1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
```

But the above property wraps the only words which have space in between but not the single long word.

So how to wrap the single long word with above row and column size properties? In lots of places I am getting advice to use

```
    view1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
    view1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;
```

But whenever I use anything other than 'none' in AutoSizeColumnsMode my column's customized width gets changed and if I use anything other than 'none' in AutoSizeRowsMode , it shows all the rows at a time and my row's customized height gets changed.

Anybody knows how to solve this problem?

**Note: It is a desktop application (Windows Form Application).**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use DataGridView CellPainting event.
Sample code:

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
        dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

        //dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells;
        //dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
        //dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[0].Value = "CELL123456789012345679801234567890";
            row.Cells[1].Value = "CELL 1";
            row.Cells[2].Value = "CELL 2";
            row.Cells[3].Value = "CELL 3";
            row.Cells[4].Value = "CELL 4";
            row.Cells[5].Value = "CELL 5";
        }

    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value == null)
            return;
        var s = e.Graphics.MeasureString(e.Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Font);
        if (s.Width > dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width)
        {
            using (
      Brush gridBrush = new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.GridColor),
      backColorBrush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.BackColor))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColorBrush, e.CellBounds);
                e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Font, Brushes.Black, e.CellBounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Height = (int)(s.Height * Math.Ceiling(s.Width / dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width));
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Improved code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value == null)
            return;

        var s = e.Graphics.MeasureString(e.Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Font);

        if (s.Width > dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width)
        {
            using (Brush gridBrush = new SolidBrush(this.dataGridView1.GridColor), backColorBrush = new SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.BackColor))
                {
                    using (Pen gridLinePen = new Pen(gridBrush))
                    {
                        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColorBrush, e.CellBounds);
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1, e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1);
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1);

                        e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), dataGridView1.Font, Brushes.Black, e.CellBounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);

                        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Height = (int)(s.Height * Math.Ceiling(s.Width / dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Width));

                        e.Handled = true;
                    }

                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @JosepLiuis: It's not working for me. What if cell0 contains space inbetween like 'Cell 123456789012345678901234567890'

Comment: In my test solution it writes CELL on first line, and the numbers on second line:

CELL 
123456789012345679801234567890

can you post your code?

Comment: @JosepLiuis: It was my fault it's working for me now but the borders around that particular cell are not getting viewed and also the content in the cell is going to the left side but I want it at center.

Comment: `Using the designer, set the center row and column to Absolute, the rest to 50 Percent.`

Comment: @JosepLiuis: In my application everything is customized background color, text color, borders n all. borders around that cell only not coming it should be white in color and set to Inset mode

Comment: you must work the CellPainting function to adjust to your settings.

Comment: In that function you are using e.CellBounds and I think because of that the borders are not coming. At the end of that function I set the BorderStyle as Inset but its not taking

Comment: @JosepLluís: I already did that and borders are visible now but text is not coming to center of the cell

Comment: Here is my sample: [link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bx2844igEgL0ZW9XTXNzdElUWW8/edit)

Comment: @JosepLluís: at this moment I am unable to open your drive link. I will check it later but is text coming to center?

Comment: do you mean to center horizontally the text?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
view.Columns[int_Desired_Column_Index].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is not a good silution but you can try:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            var source = new BindingSource();
            List<MyStruct> list = new List<MyStruct> { new MyStruct("cell 123456789012345678901234567890", "qsdsqdsqdsqdsqdb"), 
                new MyStruct("c", "d") };
            source.DataSource = list;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = source;



        }
        class MyStruct
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Adres { get; set; }


            public MyStruct(string name, string adress)
            {
                Name = name;
                Adres = adress;
            }
        }
```

[image]
[image]